how do I go through my vagrant up? It says timed out while waiting for machine to boot, that Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine
My new issue now is that when I do vagrant up it takes time to load and when it does it brings things like "timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that' vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within the configured....time period" and also shows "If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly working...in the boxes. Verify that authentication configurations....as well". How can I resolve this??
I repaired my vagrantfile, repaired and uninstall my Virtual Machine and reinstall again, I also deleted my box(ubuntu/focal64) and did vagrant init ubuntu/focal64 again

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I was unable to start my VM with vagrant up, I now start it manually and it's working fine
